# pycharm remote project with virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pycharm

I have the remote server with a few virtualenv environments (django projects).
How can I open, develop and debug these projects completely remote?

Shall I mount remote directory via sshfs to open a project?
(I can't open project other way than as local path)
I am working on debian and windows xp.

Comment: [This is a related feature request for PyCharm.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19752)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found the decision and asked the support which confirmed its:

Here is the steps:

1. copy a project to a local directory.
2. configure: tools - deployment, to upload this local copy to remote server
3. make deployment automatic: tools - deployment - "automatic upload"
4. add remote interpreter: file - settings - python interpreters - "+" - "Remote.."

The remote interpreter is the virtualenv interpreter with all packages are installed.

Debug also works, we can debug completely remote project on server using local pycharm.

Answer (score -1):

**Debian:**

From the file manager, click on `Connect To server`, connect to ssh by giving login credentials which will open your remote project on your file manager itself.

Or you can go to the server using `ssh` via terminal and edit your project via command line text editor.

**IDE:**

If you are working with IDE such as Aptana or PyCharm, you can load the project from the server itself by login credentials.